# Downlad parts of JSON file from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, json, python-3.x, http

I have been working on a python 3 app that downloads data from a Node.js server. The json file is updated regularly (this is a chat app), but my current code compares the already downloaded data to the complete data on the server. Is there a way to only download the text that is not in a variable, so as to not waste bandwidth?

Comment: With just a JSON file? No, you'll need to expose an actual API, so the client can supply e.g. the ID of the last message it received.

Comment: I am also writing the Node.js API, can I make it so that I can request this with python and the node server receives this?

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to request the message ID "and up", so that the API returns a smaller JSON file, only containing the message whose ID > the last one it receives.  Not sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an API that just returns JSON, no, there is no way to only download just the changed data, as that isn't how JSON works. The server you're downloading from has no way of knowing what your local state is. If this is a JSON file of, say, events, and they have an ID or timestamp, the NodeJS server could be written to accept a `?timestamp=last_event_you_have` or `?since=id_of_last_message` and only return objects since that time or ID, but that requires changes on the NodeJS server side of things.